# RxAndroidBle how to read notifications from several services?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rx-java, rxandroidble

I use rxandroid:2.1.0, rxjava:1.4.0 and rxandroidble:1.8.1.

I am trying to connect to the device and to receive notifications from characteristics which are located in different services (temperature service, battery service, custom service).

I've already visited tons of pages, but I haven't found any suitable solution. Maybe anyone has an idea of how this is possible to be done?

Comment: Have you tried anything up till now?

Comment: Ye, switched to standart library

Comment: According to SO principles you could have given your approach to the problem you face. It is fairly easy to setup notifications from multiple characteristics using RxAndroidBle

Comment: And how this could be done with RxAndroidBle?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my answer here [[Programmatically turning on all notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957018/programmatically-turning-on-all-notifications/55243762#55243762][1]).

I couldn't make it with rxAndroidBle library, but standart one was good enoygh for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To setup all possible notifications/indications on any given peripheral one needs to first connect to the device, then discover all services and get all eligible characteristics. On those characteristics the notifications/indications should be set and then paired with their source (if that is needed).

An example code:

```
device.establishConnection(false)
        .flatMap(connection -> connection.discoverServices()
                .map(RxBleDeviceServices::getBluetoothGattServices) // get them
                .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable) // map to individual services
                .map(BluetoothGattService::getCharacteristics) // for each service take all characteristics
                .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable) // map to individual characteristic)
                .filter(characteristic -> (characteristic.getProperties() & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE)) != 0) // consider only characteristics that have indicate or notify property
                .flatMap(characteristic -> {
                    NotificationSetupper notificationSetupper;
                    if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) {
                        notificationSetupper = setupNotifications(characteristic); // if supports notifications
                    } else {
                        notificationSetupper = setupIndications(characteristic); // else indications
                    }
                    return notificationSetupper.setupOn(connection);
                })
        )
        .subscribe(
                pair -> {
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = pair.first;
                    byte[] value = pair.second;
                    // do your thing with the emissions
                },
                throwable -> {
                    // log potential errors
                }
        );
```

Where helpers are:

```
interface NotificationSetupper {

    Observable<Pair<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, byte[]>> setupOn(RxBleConnection connection);
}

static NotificationSetupper setupNotifications(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    return connection -> connection.setupNotification(characteristic, getModeFor(characteristic))
            .compose(pairNotificationsWith(characteristic));
}

static NotificationSetupper setupIndications(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    return connection -> connection.setupIndication(characteristic, getModeFor(characteristic))
            .compose(pairNotificationsWith(characteristic));
}

static NotificationSetupMode getModeFor(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) { // a different mode is needed if a characteristic has no Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor
    UUID clientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorUuid = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    return characteristic.getDescriptor(clientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorUuid) != null ? NotificationSetupMode.DEFAULT : NotificationSetupMode.COMPAT;
}

static ObservableTransformer<Observable<byte[]>, Pair<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, byte[]>> pairNotificationsWith(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) { // to distinguish the source of notification we need to pair the value with the source
    return upstream -> upstream.flatMap(it -> it).map(bytes -> Pair.create(characteristic, bytes));
}
```